# Windows Command Prompt Dir Command to Save Text file and have no extentions in the data?

Tags: dir

I have a Dir Command I use to make a text list of a directory of files.. "dir /a /b /-p /o:gen > z-file_list.txt"

Dose anyone know how I can change this so the text list dose not contain any extensions? So just the filename?

Thanks in advance!

- EDIT -

Sorry I wasn't clear. What I mean is that his command will save a txt file with a file list of the contents of the directory.

The text file will look like this
filename.ext
filename.ext
filename.ext
filename.ext

I am trying to work out how to get the text file to look like this.
filename
filename
filename
filename

Thanks.. sorry I was unclear.

Comment: Just remove ".txt" from the file name string?

Comment: that is just the file it is writing into, the data is saved in "z-file_list.txt". It dose not effect the dir command.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  You asked how to generate a file without an extension.

Comment: oh, sorry. I have edited the question in the hopes of making it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dir` command does not have a switch or option to drop extensions.

It can be done by processing the output of `dir /b` in a `for /f` loop, though.

```
(del list.txt 2>nul) & for /f %f in ('dir /a /b /o:gen') do @echo %~nf >>list.txt
```

If you don't care about subdirectories or system/hidden files (which is what `dir /a` is for) then a plain `for` would work, too.

```
(del list.txt 2>nul) & for %f in (*) do @echo %~nf >>list.txt
```

Run `dir /?`, `del /?` and `for /?` for more details on the syntax and switches.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the CMD prompt with a little cheating with Powershell.  From the command prompt, type the follwing:

```
powershell -command "dir |select basename" > file_list.txt
```

As I said, this is a bit of a cheat, as `powershell -command` invokes the Powershell shell to run the Powershell script `dir |select basename"`.  FYI, `dir` in Powershell is just an alias for the command `get-childitem` and has nothing to do with the CMD prompt's `dir` command.  Powerhsell exectues that script and the results are returned to the CMD prompt and redirected (`>`) to the text file.